# Are combinations of variables a problem in multinomial mixture models?

Tags: clustering, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I am quite new to cluster analysis and I am currently using Gaussian-multinomial mixture models. I have a sample size of 10000 people with some continuous variables and about 14 categorical variables (let's call the categorical ones var_1, var_2, ..., var_14) that defines these people.

The thing is that I think the created clusters would be more realistic if I combined the categorical variables. However, I don't know if it is correct to include in the analysis of multinomial mixture models the combination of the categorical variables, but with repeated variables in some of these combinations. For example:

comb_1 = var_1 AND var_2 AND var_3

comb_2 = var_1 AND var_4 AND var_5

comb_3 = var_4 AND var_6 AND var_7

From the assumptions of multinomial mixture models I think I could do this but I am not totally sure. Can anyone help me?